# When I visualize a patch of red and intend that it be the same shade of red as some patch I've previously seen, do I represent a redness universal?

Tags: properties, universals, universal-and-particulars

My audiovisual imagination is very active and vivid (to the point of interfering with more objective representation much of the time), but so I am used to the "experience," if you will, of not only remembering the "properties" of things "given" beforehand, but of "copying" those properties in new imagery. I am not unsure, so much, that I can "see" something like "color universals" or "hear musical universals," etc.<sup>***!!!***</sup>: my "sight" and "hearing" of these seems about as guaranteed to me as my ability to count to the same numbers at various times, say.

What I'm more unsure about is the following pair of options:

1. When I imagine a patch of red, I apprehend the relevant universal in whole, as wholly located in a new spot (the patch of my imaginal space itself).
2. When I imagine the red patch, I am imagining a new, and proper, *part of* the relevant universal: I never witness the whole universal *per se* in its instances, but only these parts.

**Would interpreting my experience as (2) undermine my claim that I am adequately representing universals?**

---

<sup>***!!!***</sup>Suppose that I denied that I was instantiating lexical universals by writing various words down, and denied too that others were instantiating such things. Then when I, or some other, argued with myself about universals altogether, I could simply deny that the words now being used meant the same thing as the words used elsewhere, could I not? To wit, *A* says, "There are no universals," and *B* says, "Ah, but then *A* doesn't mean the same thing by the word 'universals' as I mean," and what is to be done about that?

---

**EDIT: Copying vs. sharing**

Consider the difference between copying a file from one computer to another (or on the same computer, as when you go from ABCD.exe to ABCD(1).exe), and sharing a file, without copying it, via something like the Cloud. By visualizing a previously seen patch of red, then, am I copying the file "patchofred.jpg" (so to speak) from my perception-storage to my imagination-storage, or am I sharing patchofred.jpg (whose only copy is on my perceptual "hard drive")?

Comment: Hi Kristian, a very interesting question, and one of the few of yours that I believe I have any chance of answering! I will give it some thought and get back to you.

Comment: "*There are two kinds of people in the world: those that divide people into two kinds, and those that don't.*" And you are *powerless* to stop them Muah hahaha!

Comment: I can't help thinking of "perfect pitch". Do you have that? Perfect patch seems plausible though. Perfect pickle for taste. Perfect perfume...

Comment: @ScottRowe if perfect pitch is a singing-related ability, then I don't have a perfect example of the ability, no... A lot of the time I have that overwhelming-memory thing, though, like you can rewind and rewatch huge stretches of time, and the VCR (ha! my age shows!) automatically rewinds constantly. If it were useful, I wouldn't mind, but it doesn't seem entirely useful, or at least my social circumstances remain dire.

Comment: Yes, I empathize. We all have our bears to cross. I was just mentioning other sense abilities that people are known to have which could be considered similar. I have to remain silent on the idea of Universals though.

Comment: It's not clear that you are perceiving anything in that situation. Perception (in philosophy) is generally understood as an activity of the senses. As you are not involving the senses, is it perception? What you might say is that perception is not specifically an action of the senses, but an action of that mental faculty by which the senses operate. In other words, you could observe that vision and visualization have *something* in common, some sort of mental faculty which presents to the mind as sensory input or something like it.

Comment: @DavidGudeman yes, I think I am using the word "perception" off-kilter, I wanted to use "intuition" or "apprehension" in the Kantian sense, but worried those too would come across the wrong way... maybe I should use "representation."

Comment: Reference: Sellars, Wilfried: *Empiricism and the Philosophy of Mind* ;)

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking ah, that was why my subconscious reminded me to put "given" in scare quotes!

Comment: Maybe Kant's "representation" would work. I'm not sure about "intuition", because as I understand it, intuition is specifically the faculty that represents a particular.

Comment: I think that **The Abhidharma** would be useful here also. When you are examining perception and thought, look to the folks with a 2000 year head start.

Comment: Per contemporary physicalistic representationalism there's no copy of any green stuff in your mind save ineffable qualia which is not the shareable Kantian quality category at all. Furthermore this sharing could be very well originated from token images or metaphoric tropes, no need of any non-causal mystic universals, and of course if each intentional mind's said sharing is said to resemble one of her previous sharings then there must be some resemblance token obtained to the said mind while another mind may not obtain. Shurangama sutra hinted sight tokens may even resemble sound tokens...

Comment: Your specific scenario brings up private language issues. "*Can I point to the sensation? Not in the ordinary sense. But I speak, or write the sign down, and at the same time I concentrate my attention on the sensation - and so, as it were, point to it inwardly. But what is this ceremony for?... Whatever is going to seem right to me is right. And that only means that here we can't talk about 'right'*", Wittgenstein, PI §258. You are better off pointing at a patch of red, in the *ordinary* sense, rather than imagining it. Re-imagining a color is not analogous to *either* copying or sharing.

Comment: @Conifold perhaps I mean something different by "copy" than you do, since I would not hesitate to say that if I see e.g. a book, and then imagine that same book visually, that I am copying my perceptual representation of the book. ... unless I should rather say that I am "mirroring" the outward representation, in a way analogous to the meaning of the phrase "mirror neurons"?